# Python export only parts of list to CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, export-to-csv

Please can you help.
Using Python 2.6.6.

I have list called 'results' like:

```
# This is remark only: Type for `results`: <type 'list'>
1 86561198961563884 430cf63c640accf1c90ed2a9fe2ccce4
2 86561198160451905 d3fe1c990841552483955dfa81234338
3 86561198114921980 099c88e5c344233a388c0e558d3d88c8
4 86561198160858321 85cf9fa846e0f626c2490d12e9c9919e
```

Currently writing to file 'myOutput.csv' with code:

```
import csv
with open("myOutput.csv", "wb") as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerows(results)
```

I want this in csv file: {Thus not the "first column" / rows[0]}

```
86561198961563884 430cf63c640accf1c90ed2a9fe2ccce4
86561198160451905 d3fe1c990841552483955dfa81234338
86561198114921980 099c88e5c344233a388c0e558d3d88c8
86561198160858321 85cf9fa846e0f626c2490d12e9c9919e
```

The background and why.
Already made changes to list.
Now need to go to CSV for MySQL import.

Thank you,

Comment: `writer.writerows([line[1:] for line in results])`?

Comment: Thank you very much. That worked. Please could you tell me what we call this "action, option" so I can go read and learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation) off the first item from each row.

```
writer.writerows([line[1:] for line in results])
```

`[1:]` means a slice from the element with index 1, which is the first item, all the way to the end. This forms part of a [comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34835951/what-does-list-comprehension-in-python-mean-how-does-it-work-and-how-can-i-us) that performs this slice for each row, creating a new `list` which is sent to `writer.writerows`.